# how to merge/Combine two tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

Hello I want merge two tables in oracle like below -

[image]

I tried below answer from stack overflow but not getting answer like **Output table**

[Combining Two Tables With Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408425/combining-two-tables-with-oracle-sql/18409559)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below query:

```
select * from (
select id, name, rate,total from table1
union all
select id, name, rate,total from table2
) as  t
order by t.id asc
```

Comment: facing `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` error

Answer (score 1):

use `union all`

```
select id, name, rate,total from table1
union all
select id, name, rate,total from table2
```